# Simple jQuery scrollTo doesn't work on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I tested the one or other solution of stackoverflow but it can't resolve my problem.

Here is the side:
http://web02980.p4.imv.de/
 It's a wordpress-site and I want to use a simple jQuery function to scroll from a anchor to a headline.

Here is the jQuery code http://jsfiddle.net/5phLjjce/1/
In jsfiddle it works, but not on my site.

```
function scroll($) {

    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    scroll($);
});
```

I tested the jquery-file in the header and in the footer. I tested it in the generell jquery-file and in a extra file. Nothing want to scroll.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If it works as a fiddle but not on your site it is likely more to do with other code on your site interfering with it. I think, however, you should pass an `event` to your click function and then use `event.preventDefault()` as otherwise the link will simply go to the href.

Comment: I tried a function with  this event, but no harm done. And the console doesn't show me a bug or something like else.

Comment: The script's totally different to the jsfiddle. In scrolling.js you have different code for scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I tried some other code in the last time. So it's not the same code here. But I found a solution (look at the answer of starikovs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, just replace `var $root = $('html, body');` with `var $root = $('.overflow');`. It's just a specific thing in your HTML markup.